# Naming conventions for glsl outs and ins

Tags: opengl, naming-conventions, glsl, shader

After following several different tutorials on OpenGL shaders, I noticed they all use different naming for the outs and ins.

For instance, I've seen `ex_color` `vFragColor`, `ModelViewMatrix`, `mvMatrix`, etc.

It would be nice if my shaders would be compatible with some other shaders out there without having to rename everything. Is there some kind of naming scheme, or standard I could follow that is more or less common?

Comment: I don't believe there are any naming convention schemes for user defined variables...

Comment: I like to match names with shadertoy where possible since it has a huge user base when it comes to shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no naming convention for interface variable names. You should use whatever works and makes sense for your needs.

Also, there's no need to be "compatible" with other people shaders if you don't copy and paste their code into your own.

Comment: That's what I was hoping I could do, or at least have a predefined cheat sheet so I would be consistent myself.

Comment: Copy-and-paste coding never helped anyone. Not in the long-term.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm imagining that on a big project it would be nice if I could say, let's use this or that naming scheme. So mixing one vertex shader with a different fragment shader won't be a problem. Correct me if I'm wrong but vertex and fragment shaders are not always created in pairs?

Comment: @bobbaluba: My point is that it isn't very hard to *write* a naming convention. If you're collaborating with people, just put the document in source control or something.

Comment: @bobbaluba: Also keep in mind, that glShaderSource takes an array of strings, with the idea being, that you can implement sort of an include system. So you could write a set of headers providing predefined preambles for your shaders. This would enforce a naming scheme for your project.

Comment: @NicolBolas naming conventions **are** useful and it's not about copy-paste

Comment: @KamilTomšík: Naming conventions are useful for communicating important information to other people reading the code. But how important is it *really* to know if a variable is an input or an output just from reading a statement? If you're writing to it, then it's some kind of output even if it's not a shader-stage output. And if you're reading from it, do you really care if it's a shader input or a uniform? What you care about is that it is a "vertex position" or a "texture coordinate" or whatever; how it got there is not really relevant.